# What is the best way to level a tree log?

Tags: woodworking, wooden-furniture, level

I'm making an end table/floor lamp from a 3 ft cut log. What's going to be the easiest or best way to level the bottom and top of this piece?
I thought about throwing it up on some saw horses and using the chainsaw to get it approximately level, then sand it to get it perfectly level.
Just curious if anyone had a better solution.

Comment: Unless this thing is huge, you'll be putting a top and legs on it anyways. You seem confident about your chainsaw skills, that should suffice for close enough. If your top is glass, you may want to get a little more precise.

Comment: a top, but no legs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They make attachments for chainsaws to do rough on-site milling. It's basically a guide to square off a log.

Once you have it squared off, you may want to go with a power plane which would be  abit faster than sanding.

Answer (score 6):

It is also possible to do the final smoothing of the rough squared off faces by using a router. The router rides in a set of movable supports that you arrange over the end of the log and the router bit can cut to a smooth finish across the whole log face. As you make each pass with the router you slide the movable supports over an appropriate amount and then take the next pass.

The starting point is to afix (clamp) a frame of two straight boards in parallel along each side of the log. Then at right angles to these you have the router support slides. The router makes passes by feeding the router along the support sliders. The next pass is arranged by moving the sliders along the first parallel support boards. The following picture attempts to show a top down view of the setup.

[image]

Comment: Sounds good, but doesn't seem to be the best/easiest way. Thanks though